# Ionic Cannot read property 'xxx' of null while value is exist

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to return my products based on their id's and I get data successfully but somehow view won't load instead returns this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'newprice' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProductDetailsPage.html:27)
```

## Images

`Network tab`

[image: one]

`Console`

[image: two]

As you see I can return my data from server also newprice has value.

## Code

`product.page.ts`

```
product = null;
loading: any;

constructor(
  private productService: ProductsService,
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  public loadingController: LoadingController,
  private menu: MenuController
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
}

getData() {

  let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.productService.getProductsDetails(id).subscribe(res => {
    this.product = res;
    console.log(res); // returned in second image as full product details
    console.log('newprice', res['newprice']);  // returned in second image as full product newprice
  });

});
```

`product.page.html`

```
<h4 class="productTitle">{{product.name}}</h4>
<ion-col size="9">
  <div *ngIf="product.newprice != null else noDiscount">
    <div>
      <span class="newPrice">{{product.newprice | currency: 'Rp ' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'}}</span> <br>
      <del>{{product.price | currency: 'Rp ' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'}}</del>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-template #noDiscount>
    <span class="newPrice">{{product.price | currency: 'Rp ' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'}}</span>
  </ng-template>
</ion-col>
```

**More**

This is the link that supposed to open product page:

```
<img routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="['/', 'products', product.id]" [src]="product.photo">
```

and here is route of it:

```
{
    path: 'products/:id',
    loadChildren: './pages/product-details/product-details.module#ProductDetailsPageModule'
  },
```

**Thoughts**

I think the problem is related to this line:

```
let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

as it trying to get data based on id from address bar which isn't exist, this function fires before page reloads.

> I'm not sure if that's the problem or not please share with me your
>   solutions and thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

All I had to do was adding `*ngIf="product"` before actually start to return products data so I added at the top of my page `<ion-row padding *ngIf="product">` now everything is working fine.

Hope it help others as well.

Comment: also you can use async pipe since you're getting value from observable

Comment: it is using async to avoid mess up the question i just shared important parts.

Comment: Yep check someone answer above

Answer (score 0):

As product is going to available after ajax call you can make use of async pipe here to resolve your issue

```
product: Observable<Product>;

this.product = this.productService.getProductsDetails(id);
```

html

```
  <p >{{ product.newprice | async }}</p>
```